# Different Version of DLL for .NET framework

Tags: .net

We have installed .NET framework Version 4.0.30319 in our development environment and Production environment.

But we found that DLLs are different (date/size) on these machine.

Developer Machine: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07 GHz, Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1)-64bit, 8 GB RAM, .NET Framework v4.0.30319

Production Server: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 @ 2.40 GHz (2x CPU Quad Core), Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise-64bit, 48 GB RAM, .NET Framework v4.0.30319

What could be reason for different DLL version for same .NET framework ?

Please let me know if any further any information required.

Comment: The smaller one could be the Client Profile only version - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you mean and explain whether you're having an actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET 4.0.30319 framework could actually mean 3 things:

1. .Net 4.0
2. .Net 4.0 Client Version (which is smaller)
3. .Net 4.5 (Installing 4.5, actually modifies the 4.0 installation directory since it is just a series of new features and bugfixes to 4.0. The 4.0 interface is unchanged though)

Check to see that you installed the same exact thing on all machines, and that they didn't have a different version installed already.